# Text: frequency table

Tags: r, string

I want the number of times each letter occurred in the `text`.

```
text <-c("Bio; Chem; Law","Bio; Stat", "Bio; Chem; Law; Stat")
```

The code `table(text)` gives a result of:

```
   Bio; Chem; Law   Bio; Chem; Law; Stat   Bio; Stat 
                2                      0           0
```

which is not the one I need. The output that I'm looking for is:

```
Bio   3
Chem  2  
Law   2
Stat  2
```

Can one help me, please? Tnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
text_splitted <- str_split(text, ";") %>% unlist()
table(text_splitted)

#> Chem   Law  Stat   Bio 
#>    2     2     2     3
```